# Elasticsearch - return only specific fields for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch

I have autocomplete setup w/ jquery ajax and would like to only return specific fields, not the entire response. I have:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/music/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
    "song-suggest" : {
        "text" : "n",
        "completion" : {
            "fields" : ["suggest"],
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}'
```

I get an error:

```
{
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":0,
      "failed":5,
      "failures":[
         {
            "index":"music",
            "shard":3,
            "reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][3] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [fields]]; "
         },
         {
            "index":"music",
            "shard":4,
            "reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][4] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [fields]]; "
         },
         {
            "index":"music",
            "shard":1,
            "reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][1] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [fields]]; "
         },
         {
            "index":"music",
            "shard":2,
            "reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][2] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [fields]]; "
         },
         {
            "index":"music",
            "shard":0,
            "reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][0] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [fields]]; "
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am obviously doing something wrong and can't figure out how to correctly get the results. (I should also mention I am new to elasticsearch).

EDIT: I have elasticsearch running behind nginx so if there's a solution in nginx to get only the "suggest" field that would be acceptable.

**EDIT #2:** My mapping

```
{
   "song":{
      "properties":{
         "suggest":{
            "type":"completion"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT #3:**

Leaving out the "fields" parameter gives:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "s": [
    {
      "text": "Kate",
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 4,
      "options": [
        {
          "text": "Kate Bush",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "text": "Kate Middleton",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The end user doesn't need to see "_shards" nor the original query. Ideally, return something like:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Kate Bush"
  },
  {
    "text": "Kate Middleton"
  }
]
```

**EDIT #4:**

Victor's suggestion returns the following error:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 0,
    "failed": 5,
    "failures": [
      {
        "index": "music",
        "shard": 1,
        "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][1] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]; "
      },
      {
        "index": "music",
        "shard": 0,
        "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][0] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]; "
      },
      {
        "index": "music",
        "shard": 2,
        "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][2] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]; "
      },
      {
        "index": "music",
        "shard": 3,
        "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][3] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]; "
      },
      {
        "index": "music",
        "shard": 4,
        "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][4] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]; "
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your mapping

Comment: @mallik: added my mapping. thx!. BTW, I am working off the example from http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: 'suggest' doesn't support 'fields' parameter, where did you find that is does in the guide?

Comment: Remove "fields" : ["suggest"], from your request

Comment: @Undefined_variable: That removes the error but doesn't answer the underlying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To make autocomplete work, you can just use "prefix" search with wildcard like

   ```
   {
       //query with wildcard to perform prefix search
       "query":{"query_string" : {
           "default_field" : "my_field",
           "query" : "search_prefix*"
       }},   
       //return field "my_field" and not the whole document  
       "fields":["my_field"]
   }
   ```
2. Elasticsearch is designed to return this strange object, and getting the actual array for autocomplete can be done a) with server-side code, which requests elasticsearch and transforms result for you; b) just using fields you are interested in, not looking on the others.

Comment: @llamawithabowlcut I meant not using suggest request at all, actually. The whole code in answer meant to be template for elasticsearch request.

Comment: but the question is about the suggest request.